# How to add a role to a user through dm

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So the user joins the server and has to dm the bot and then the bot should give him a specific role (Member). Here a part of my code:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.type == "dm") {
        user = msg.author.id;
        if (msg.content.startsWith("-bind")) {
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                if (msg.content.includes(keys[i]) && msg.content.includes(keys_perma[i])) {

                    keys[i] = user;

                    let server = client.guilds.cache.get('792890734139015218')
                    var memberRole = server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Member")
                    let member = server.members.cache.get(msg.author.id)

                    member.roles.add(memberRole)

                    temp = 1;

                    msg.author.send("Key bound!");

                    break;
                }
```

But member.roles.add(memberRole) gives me the error: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

I hope anyone can help me with that :)

Comment: Are you building the bot for a specific server or is it a public bot?

Comment: for a specific server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member` is returning undefined, It's always best to fetch a member rather than rely on cache. For this example I will use `Promise#then()` to fetch a member.

```
let member = server.members.fetch(msg.author.id).then(m => {
   m.roles.add(memberRole);
});
```